# JavaScript Promises and Function Return Differences

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

What is the difference between the following two functions as far as promises are concerned?

```
var service = {
    someFunction: function() {
        return $http.get('url').then(function (response) {
            return response;
        });
    },
    someFunction2: function() {
        return $http.get('url');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second returns a promise so that the calling function (not shown in your code) can do something with it.

The first one does exactly the same thing, but it also uses the promise to define a function that will run then the response comes back. That function does (effectively) nothing, since when the HTTP response arrives, it returns to the calling function (`then`) which doesn't care about the response.

Comment: ? They do effectively exactly the same thing

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference - the identity function in the first example is not needed but doesn't cause any observable difference to outside.